# Error when importing tensorflow in Spyder

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, gpu, spyder

I just installed tensorflow on the new laptop.

(Anaconda 4.3.24, Python 3.6.1, TensorFlow: 1.2.1, GPU: NVIDIA 1060 6GB)

Four problems currently.

**{1} "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime" error in Spyder**

```
File "D:/Programs/Codes-Python/OpenCVtest.py", line 13, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in 
swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in 
import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

**{2} ...but tensorflow loads without (much) problem from command prompt**

The confusing thing is that when I load the tensorflow via anaconda prompt -> activate tensorflow -> python -> import tensorflow: Then there is no error while importing tensorflow.

How come? If the tensorflow library is installed only for certain environment the error message in Spyder should be "No Module Named TensorFlow"....

**{3} Some discrepancies when running an example**

Now when I run the test code in anaconda prompt:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
```

I get the following 'errors'?

```
2017-08-14 23:39:37.137745: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-14 23:39:37.137929: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-14 23:39:37.139157: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-14 23:39:37.139677: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-14 23:39:37.140599: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-14 23:39:37.141239: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-14 23:39:37.141915: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-14 23:39:37.142529: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

But I can still run the last part of the test "print(sess.run(hello))" and get the following result.

```
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

The 'b' in front of Hello is not supposed to be there, but always present when I run the code. Why?

**{4} No known Device error - GPU unrecognised?**
Lastly, when I check the device being used, tensorflow does not seem to recognise the GPU. Why? I've tried uninstalling, re-installing tensorflow and tensorflow-GPU separately to no avail.

```
>>> sess = tf.Session(config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
Device mapping: no known devices.
2017-08-14 23:50:42.624086: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\direct_session.cc:265] Device mapping:
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
CN

Answer (score 0):

For your {1} question, because you activate Tensorflow in {2}, I guess your Spyder is installed in different enviroment. Maybe you could try to change the python interpreter of Spyder from Preference->Console->Advanced settings.
For {4}, did you install Nvidia Cuda tool?
Hope this will help.

Best,
Robin

Comment: Thanks, Robin. CUDA 8.0 (and cuDNN) has been installed, although now I am unsure about whether it's been installed 'correctly'. The sample program from NVIDIA is no longer provided for verifying installation.

Answer (score 0):

To install spyder in the tensorflow enviroment. 
source activate tensorflow(linux) or activate tensorflow(your enviroment you created,if any)(windows) first, then, conda install spyder.
***activate tensorflow enviroment first and then start spyder* each time.**
good luck, Walker